# Is it possible to change In-App-Purchase type in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I want to know that in iOS is that possible to change type from Auto-renewable to Consumable Or vice versa , after product configuration completed and tested with sandbox user?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: No I don't think it is, you need to create a new product

Answer (score 1):

**No, you can not.**

It lets you change the product prices without updating the app, but those you setup in the console are final.

You may create other products at any time, they would have nonetheless, a different ID which you may be required to update depending your Apps needs.

In a nutshell, prices and features, you can. The nature of the product itself you can not, 1$ to 3$ is OK. Consumable to Non-Consumable Nope.

I quote Apple:

> Before you start coding, you need to configure products in App Store Connect for your app to interact with. As you develop your app, you can add and remove products and refine or reconfigure your existing products.
>
> Products are reviewed when you submit your app as part of the app review process. Before users can buy a product, it must be approved by the reviewer and you must mark it as “cleared for sale” in App Store Connect.

[image]

Therefore, it's a sticky and cumbersome process, no changes allowed.

I hope I helped, if you need any further help please comment. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **no, you can't**.

Here is the **Apple** documentation about it: [Create an in-app purchase](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devae49fb316).

If you really need to change the `In-App Purchase Type`, you have to add a new `In-App Purchase` in **AppStore Connect** and set the right configuration for it, then remove the old one.